# How can I let my HTTPS frontend server connect with my HTTP rest API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, ssl, amazon-ec2, https

I have a React.js web app deployed via Google Firebase hosting. I also have an express Rest API deployed via AWS EC2. I have been so far unable to get the React app to interact with the express API because it is using HTTP. I tried to get all the SSL/cert stuff figured out to enable HTTPS on the backend but it seems like it will not work because the cert is not signed by a Certificate Authority.

Is there any workaround or other solution here? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A web browser will not accept a self-signed SSL certificate. In order to generate a legitimate SSL certificate you must first own a domain name.

You need to purchase a domain, and point your domain or subdomain to the EC2 instance. Then you need to create an SSL certificate that actually matches that domain name or subdomain, using an SSL provider like [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) that will actually be accepted by modern web browsers.

Finally you will need to use that domain name in your API calls.

---

You could place a Load Balancer, or CloudFront distribution, or AWS API Gateway, in front of the EC2 server, at which point you could use a free AWS ACM SSL certificate.

---

If you don't want to purchase a domain name, you could still place CloudFront or API Gateway in front of the server and use their default endpoint which will also provide SSL.

Comment: *Amazon API Gateway :)